# Getting a cookie value using libcurl and C++

Tags: c++, windows, cookies, libcurl

I use libcurl to send a request to a page. And the page set a cookie on local. The problem is how can I get the value of a single cookie into a variable. 
Ps I have set the tag COOKIEFILE AND COOKIEJAR

Answer (score 0):

You can export all cookies a libcurl handle keeps, using something like this:

[curl_easy_getinfo](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_getinfo.html)(..., [CURLINFO_COOKIELIST](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_getinfo.html#CURLINFOCOOKIELIST), ...)

That gives you a list, then you can just scan through that list to find the one(s) you need.